# Why pnpm failed to install on Azure App Service?

Tags: npm, next.js, azure-devops, pnpm

I just switched from npm to pnpm by following thess steps:

0. `npm install pnpm -g`.
1. Remove the `node_modules`.
2. Remove `package-lock.json`.
3. `pnpm install`

Also, I added this line to my `package.json`:

`"preinstall": "npx only-allow pnpm",`

But when I deployed the app, I got this issue:

[image]

This is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "credium-gersthofen-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx only-allow pnpm",
    "predev": "node scripts/babel/backup.js",
    "prebuild": "node scripts/babel/backup.js",
    "precypress-run-component": "node scripts/babel/restore.js",
    "precypress-open-component": "node scripts/babel/restore.js",
    "precypress-run-e2e": "node scripts/babel/restore.js",
    "precypress-open-e2e": "node scripts/babel/restore.js",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "test": "jest",
    "test-watch": "jest --watch",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "lint-staged": "npx lint-staged",
    "lint-style": "npx stylelint src/*.css src/**/**/*.css",
    "cypress-open-component": "cypress open --component",
    "cypress-open-e2e": "cypress open --e2e",
    "cypress-run-component": "cypress run --component --headless",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/tailwindcss": "^0.2.0",
    "@mdx-js/loader": "^3.0.0",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^3.0.0",
    "@next/mdx": "^14.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@sentry/nextjs": "^7.80.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.2",
    "@tremor/react": "^3.11.0",
    "@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/mdx": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "20.4.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "chai-colors": "^1.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "contentlayer": "^0.3.4",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^10.0.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.4",
    "i18next": "^23.4.3",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.1.0",
    "i18next-resources-to-backend": "^1.1.4",
    "istanbul-lib-coverage": "^3.2.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.292.0",
    "next": "^14.0.2",
    "next-contentlayer": "^0.3.4",
    "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^13.0.3",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.15",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "sharp": "^0.32.3",
    "stylelint": "^15.11.0",
    "swr": "^2.2.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.0.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "tsconfig-paths-jest": "^0.0.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.18",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.7.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.7.0",
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.11.0",
    "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript": "^1.0.2",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.5.1",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.5.1",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.5.1",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.8",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.5.1",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^7.5.1",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.5.1",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^6.1.1",
    "cypress": "^13.0.0",
    "cypress-react-selector": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.46.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.15",
    "fetch-mock": "^9.11.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-next-dynamic": "^1.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
    "msw": "^1.2.5",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "storybook": "^7.5.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^34.0.0",
    "stylelint-prettier": "^4.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

Though the pipeline went successfully:

[image]

This is my Azure Pipeline configuration:

```yaml
# Node.js with React Pipeline
# Build a Node.js project that uses React using Azure DevOps.

trigger:
  - dev

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: Install
    displayName: "Install"
    jobs:
      - job: InstallJob
        displayName: "Install Node.js and Dependencies"
        steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: "^20.x"
            displayName: "Install Node.js"
          - script: |
              npm install -g pnpm
              pnpm install
            displayName: "Install Dependencies"

  - stage: Tests
    displayName: "Run Unit and Component Tests"
    jobs:
      - job: TestsJob
        displayName: "Run Unit and Component Tests"
        steps:
          - script: |
              npm install -g pnpm
              pnpm install
              pnpm test
              pnpm cypress-run-component
            displayName: "Run Unit and Component Tests"

  - stage: Build
    displayName: "Build Application"
    jobs:
      - job: BuildJob
        displayName: "Build Application"
        steps:
          - script: |
              npm install -g pnpm
              pnpm install
              pnpm build
            displayName: "Build Application"

  - stage: ArchiveAndPublish
    displayName: "Archive and Publish Artifacts"
    jobs:
      - job: ArchiveAndPublishJob
        displayName: "Archive Build Artifacts and Publish"
        steps:
          - task: ArchiveFiles@2
            inputs:
              rootFolderOrFile: "."
              includeRootFolder: false
              archiveType: "zip"
              archiveFile: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip"
              replaceExistingArchive: true
          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
              ArtifactName: "drop"
              publishLocation: "Container"
```

Comment: How Is the error in your screenshot reproduced? Did it happen when you were running `pnpm install` command in the container hosing your app in Azure App Services? Based on the phrased findings, may I assume your `pnpm` installation works on the `ubuntu-latest` pipeline agent environment but only fails in your webapp container? If my understanding is correct, please note that Azure DevOps is simply an automation tool for deployment and your commands from a pipeline is running on pipeline agent rather than on your web container.

Comment: In addition, your current YAML pipeline doesn't show how the `$(Build.BuildId).zip` is deployed to your app to Azure. In the `ArchiveAndPublish` stage, it simply archived the files from `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` and published the zip file onto piepline storage container rather than the `wwwroot` path of your web app. So, you need to mannually download and deploy the zip file to Azure Web App after it is generated in pipeline?

Comment: To isolate the issue, you may test to generate the zip file and deploy your app from local machine and see if the issue is reproducible. Currently you are only reaching the subcommunity with `Azure DevOps` tag, but there is no issue in your pipeline. If your query is related Azure App Services, please consider editing the tags of this thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by one of your "scripts" in your package.json. Specifically this one:

```
"preinstall": "npx only-allow pnpm",
```

Somewhere in your deployment, there must be an attempt to install packages using another package manager. This is what is causing the error. I can't find the exact root of the issue with the level of detail provided in your question. But I can suggest reading the azure app services documentation as I think by default app services tries to run npm install. This could be the cause of your error.

Hope that helps a little! :)